# C# Induce class name through generics and dependency injection?

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I am using an external FileHelpers library to validate my csv file by creating a class where the properties would match the csv columns
http://www.filehelpers.net/example/ErrorHandling/ErrorMode.SaveAndContinue/

With this implementation I need to pass a class to initiate validation engine as below

```
var engine = new DelimitedFileEngine<Customer>();
```

However I have different type of files, hence the class name `Customer` needs to be parameterized.

Based on some value, the class can either be Customer , Employee and so on.

I was trying to use

```
public List<T> ValidateFileData<T>(T className)
{

var engine = new DelimitedFileEngine<T>();
}
```

I am not really sure how to use this.
And also how to set Customer or Employee class based on some string value and pass as a parameter to this method?.
I have an option to use unitycontainer and do dependency injection. Any leads and insights on how my desgin should be wil be helpful..

Comment: Remove the parameter, simply use: `public void ValidateFileData<T>()`, and call it like this: `ValidateFileData<Customer>();`. If you actually need to pass in a customer as well then your current code is OK already. What is the issue here?

Comment: Hmm. But DelimitedFileEngine<T> is actually a syntax error. The Type T must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter T in the generic type

Comment: There is no information in your question about that. That must be a constaint declared with `DelimitedFileEngine<T>`, but you have not mentioned any of that. Note that you cannot specify a *variable*  in place of the `T`, you must specify a *type*. Since you're not showing your code I can only speculate about the reason for your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want the logic to work like this pseudocode:

```
IDelimitedFileEngine engine= null; // because you're programming to interfaces, right?
switch(className)
{
   case "Customer":
      engine = new DelimitedFileEngine<Customer>();
      break;
   case "Employee":
      engine = new DelimitedFileEngine<Employee>();
      break;
}
```

There really isn't a way to map a string parameter to the type `T` of a generic class `Something<T>` except by the sort of case-by-case logic I use above.  Not if you want to assign the result to a variable that will work regardless of what `T` is.  (Unless `Something<T>` is based on the non-generic `ISomething` as in my example.)

So, what can you do?  Well, you can experiment with `System.Linq.Expressions`, which lets you dynamically build up expressions that can be compiled and executed.  I've had mixed results with that, but it might work for you.

You can give up the idea of using generics and use old-fashioned reflection.  It will be slower than you might like, but speed may not be your primary concern.

```
var targetType = Type.GetType(className);
var engine = new DelimitedFileEngine(targetType);
```

This would have the advantage of being adaptable to any new type you wanted to throw at it, rather than being limited (as in my example) to the types you code it to know about.

You could even, with the help of reflection, do something equivalent to what the XmlSerializer does, and generate your own helper assembly on the fly.

Or you can bite the bullet and use the logic I have above, ugly and non-expandable though it is.

Comment: Thanks. For simplicity sake, I had mentioned void. But my return is actually List<T>, Can I say List<targetType>? It doesnt seem to work

Comment: Lasse V. Karlson is right, in his comments to your question:  you can't subsitute a variable (like `targetType`) for a type. The type of a generic type must be specified at design/compile time.  It can't be set at run time except through the kind of mechanism I show in my first example.

Comment: There's no way to say that a single variable is sometimes List<Customer> and sometimes List<Employee>, unless you declare it to be a type that both have as an ancestor (like the non-generic `IList`.)

Comment: Can I send List<object>?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "send", but I'd think so. But it depends on what you do with it.

Comment: Be aware, though, that `List<object>` is not an ancestor of `List<Customer>`, even if `object` is an ancestor of `Customer`.